# SQLiteDatabase.query orderBy cluase: "SELECT": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I found the below syntax for orderBy clause:

```
        String orderBy = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " ORDER BY " + COL_NAME + ";";
```

but it gives this error:

> E/SQLite Exception: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, organization, phone, address, email, web_ad, inf, birthday FROM contact ORDER BY SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY name;

I want to sort the entries in my database alphabetically according to their names using SQLiteDatabase.query() method.

```
    String orderBy = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " ORDER BY " + COL_NAME + ";";

    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.query( ContactHelper.TABLE, projection, null, null, null, null, orderBy);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("SQLite Exception", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

what's the mistake I'm making?

Comment: SELECT expressions
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ];

Comment: for example SELECT *
FROM customers
ORDER BY last_name;

Comment: I guess I'm using the format you mentioned. ain't I? @KanzariyaHitesh

Comment: please write your original query i can help you.

Comment: This is not your full code, right? How do you use the string `orderby`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `orderBy` argument of the `query()` method should contain only the column's name and not the full `select` statement.
Change to this:

```
db.query( ContactHelper.TABLE, projection, null, null, null, null, COL_NAME);
```

In general that argument should contain the `ORDER BY` clause of the statement *excluding the `ORDER BY` itself*.

`ASC` is optional. If you omit it then `ASC` will be used. 
If you want `DESC` then you should write: `COL_NAME + " DESC"`
You can find more here: [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: So how does it know it should sort asc or desc?

Comment: ASC is optional. If you omit it then ASC will be used. If you want DESC then you should write: `COL_NAME + " DESC"`

Comment: @forpas you are right. check your output dude. mahadi